# What is this Xenomorph-like monster from TMNT?

Tags: character-identification, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

On YouTube in a video showing off the arcade game *Turtles in Time*, one of the enemies was a monster similar in appearance to the Xenomorphs from the *Alien* films. Has such a character ever appeared in any of the comics or TV shows?

[image: creature that looks like a yellow xenomorph]

Comment: That's a horrible way to talk about Master Splinter.

Answer (score 45):

It's a Pizza Monster, and it does appear elsewhere. They appear in a 1987 episode of the TV series, [The Case of the Killer Pizzas](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/The_Case_of_the_Killer_Pizzas):

[image]

The plot of this episode hints ever so slightly at Alien: Pizza Monster eggs look like meatballs and they were put on pizza to try to trick the turtles. If the turtles had eaten the "meatball pizza" (instead of it being put in the microwave and hatching without being eaten), I think we all know [what would happen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsD6AL3HJtM)...

Another cool thing to note is that Toy Manufacturer NECA made a yellow [Sewer Mutation Warrior Alien](https://www.cbr.com/neca-sdcc-pizza-monsters-alien-xenomorph-tmnt/) as a reference to this.

Comment: [I think you posted the wrong alien video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-sBROXalU4).

Comment: "Alien: Pizza Monster" — oddly, the movie that really put the franchise back on track.